# Pyside2 QGuiApplication, Gui freeze on button Clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml, pyside2

I'm  writing a desktop application with QML ,Pyside2 and QGuiApplication
the problem is when i click on any button Gui freezes , code execute and Gui returns to normal state.
i searched and found out the problem is single threading of my application .
so i tried to make it multi thread
i tried :

```
QGuiApplication.processEvents()
```

and :

```
app = QGuiApplication()
app.processEvents()
```

in pyQT5 i know this is the answer and handle's the problem :

```
QApplication.processEvents()
```

as documentation says [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) the function :

```
processEvents()
```

should work but not working!

this is my Qml calling function :

```
RoundButton{
     icon.source :"icons/baseline_play_arrow_black_48dp"
     onClicked: DataVisClass.road_analysis()
}
```

this is DataVisClass.py :

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication

class DataVis(QObject):
    def __init__(self,app):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = app
        self.roadAnalyser = RoadAnalyser()

    @Slot()
    def road_analysis(self):
        self.roadAnalyser.centrality(True, True, 'Piedmont, California, USA', "drive_service", "betweenness_centrality", self.app)
```

and  RoadAnalyser.py:

```
class RoadAnalyser:
    def centrality(self, logs, use_cache, place, net_type, alg_type, app):
        app.processEvents()
        QGuiApplication.processEvents()
        ox.config(log_console=logs, use_cache=use_cache)
        # place = 'Piedmont, California, USA'
        G = ox.graph_from_address(place, network_type=net_type)
        # G = ox.graph_from_address(place, network_type='drive_service')

        gdf = ox.gdf_from_place(place)
        area = ox.projection.project_gdf(gdf).unary_union.area

        # calculate basic and extended network stats, merge them together, and display
        stats = ox.basic_stats(G, area=area)
        extended_stats = ox.extended_stats(G, ecc=True, bc=True, cc=True)
        for key, value in extended_stats.items():
            stats[key] = value
            QGuiApplication.processEvents()
        pd.Series(stats)

        G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
        max_node, max_bc = max(extended_stats[alg_type].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
        # max_node, max_bc = max(extended_stats['betweenness_centrality'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
        print("Best node is : ",max_bc,max_node)

        # nc = get_node_colors_by_stat(G_projected, data=extended_stats['betweenness_centrality'])
        nc = get_node_colors_by_stat(G_projected, data=extended_stats[alg_type])
        # for each in nc :
        #     print(each)
        fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, fig_height=6, node_color=nc, node_size=20, node_zorder=2,
                                edge_linewidth=2, edge_color='#333333', bgcolor='k')
        # for each in extended_stats['betweenness_centrality'].items():
        #     print(each)
```

Thank you

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry the project is very big but i made a small path of my code . thanks

Comment: If you're doing threads in PySide, you should be sure to use QThreads.As an alternative to threads, I think you can use `singleShot()` from QTimer to do simple asynchronous execution

Comment: @bfris its just one thread and Gui

Comment: @mohsen. Sorry you mentioned multi-threading. `processEvents()` does not really do any mulithreading for you. In some cases, you can use it to make sure windows are refreshed when you want. `singleShot` is a simple way to fire a process that will run independently of the GUI loop. I think.

Comment: @bfris processEvents is always a dumb solution since it only hides the underlying problem: freezing the gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time consuming tasks should not be run in the main thread as they block the eventloop, and one effect of this is freezing. The solution is to run it in another thread:

- Delete everything related to "app" or QXApplication as it is unnecessary

  ```
  class RoadAnalyser:
      def centrality(self, logs, use_cache, place, net_type, alg_type):
          ox.config(log_console=logs, use_cache=use_cache)
          # place = 'Piedmont, California, USA'
          G = ox.graph_from_address(place, network_type=net_type)
          # G = ox.graph_from_address(place, network_type='drive_service')

          gdf = ox.gdf_from_place(place)
          area = ox.projection.project_gdf(gdf).unary_union.area

          # calculate basic and extended network stats, merge them together, and display
          stats = ox.basic_stats(G, area=area)
          extended_stats = ox.extended_stats(G, ecc=True, bc=True, cc=True)
          for key, value in extended_stats.items():
              stats[key] = value
          pd.Series(stats)

          G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
          max_node, max_bc = max(extended_stats[alg_type].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
          # max_node, max_bc = max(extended_stats['betweenness_centrality'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
          print("Best node is : ", max_bc, max_node)

          # nc = get_node_colors_by_stat(G_projected, data=extended_stats['betweenness_centrality'])
          nc = get_node_colors_by_stat(G_projected, data=extended_stats[alg_type])
          # for each in nc :
          #     print(each)
          fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(
              G,
              fig_height=6,
              node_color=nc,
              node_size=20,
              node_zorder=2,
              edge_linewidth=2,
              edge_color="#333333",
              bgcolor="k",
          )
  ```
- Use threading.Thread

  ```
  import threading


  class DataVis(QObject):
      def __init__(self, app):
          super().__init__()
          self.app = app
          self.roadAnalyser = RoadAnalyser()

      @Slot()
      def road_analysis(self):

          threading.Thread(
              target=self.roadAnalyser.centrality,
              args=(
                  True,
                  True,
                  "Piedmont, California, USA",
                  "drive_service",
                  "betweenness_centrality",
              ),
          ).start()
  ```

#### Update

If you want to send information from the thread then signals must be used

```
class DataVis(QObject):
    fooSignal = Signal(str)

    # ...

    @Slot()
    def road_analysis(self):

        threading.Thread(
            target=self.roadAnalyser.centrality,
            args=(
                True,
                True,
                "Piedmont, California, USA",
                "drive_service",
                "betweenness_centrality",
                self.fooSignal
            ),
        ).start()
```

```
class RoadAnalyser:
    def centrality(self, logs, use_cache, place, net_type, alg_type, signal):
        # ...
        signal.emit("foo")
```

```
Connections{
    target: DataVisClass
    function onFooSignal(msg){
         console.log(msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: sir . can i ask you another Question ? when the function is over i add an return statement in RoadAnalyser.py . how i could say Gui do this work throw the python code ? because its multi thred now  GUI runs and i cannot use return ?

Comment: @mohsen If you want to transmit information between threads then you must use signals

Comment: eyllanesc . could you send me an example of setting a text to a Lable after ending function . I'm new and its alittle hard

Comment: WORKED AGAIN ! pure nice and Informative . you helped me a lot .. **THANK YOU**